# IronRuby Hash to C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, interop, ironruby

**How to convert Ruby Hash to C# Dictionary?**

Do we have any built-in function...or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Net Dictionary type is a generic type which need special treatment in Ironruby. By my knowledge you cannot cast a hash to a dictionary in ironruby. But it should not be hard to write a helper function that does the conversion for you. You may even open up the hash class in ruby and include the helper inside the hash so you can return a dictionary.

See the link below how this is done in C#.

[convert HashTable to Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455822/convert-hashtable-to-dictionary-in-c-sharp)