# Hashtable to Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashtable, c#-2.0

I am trying to convert a hashtable to disctionary and found a a question here:
[convert HashTable to Dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455822/convert-hashtable-to-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

```
public static Dictionary<K,V> HashtableToDictionary<K,V> (Hashtable table)
{
    return table
        .Cast<DictionaryEntry> ()
        .ToDictionary (kvp => (K)kvp.Key, kvp => (V)kvp.Value);
}
```

When I try to use it, there is an error in table.Cast; intellisense does not show "Cast" as a valid method.

Comment: C# 2 does not support LINQ, so you can't do that.

Comment: do you have `using System.Linq`?

Comment: Thank you Sebastian; that was my issue; I was missing the "using .." line. The line of code that I have now works just fine. I also tried "Dictionary<string,int> dict = HashtableToDictionary<string, int>(htOffice);" where my hash table was using a string as key and an int as value. Not sure how to mark your response as the answer.

Answer (score 8):

`Enumerable.Cast` doesn't exist in .NET 2, nor does most of the LINQ related methods (such as `ToDictionary`).

You'll need to do this manually via looping:

```
public static Dictionary<K,V> HashtableToDictionary<K,V> (Hashtable table)
{
    Dictionary<K,V> dict = new Dictionary<K,V>();
    foreach(DictionaryEntry kvp in table)
        dict.Add((K)kvp.Key, (V)kvp.Value);
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: One cool note is you **can** use extension methods in 2.0 if you are using a compiler that supports it (VS 2008 and above). [You just need to declare the attribute flag the compiler transparently adds when you create a extension method.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346554/can-i-use-extension-methods-and-linq-in-net-2-0-or-3-0)

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable.Cast` is in the `System.Linq` namespace. Unfortunately, LINQ is not part of .NET 2. You will have to upgrade to at least version 3.5.