# Change a HashTable to a Dictionnary

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455822/convert-hashtable-to-dictionary-in-c-sharp). But there's no example to make it work. So I tried it on my own.
Here's my code:

```
public void AskServer(List<Kvp> kvps)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    Hashtable headers = form.headers;
    if (this._lastCookies != string.Empty) {
        headers.Add("Cookie", this._lastCookies);
    }
    foreach (var arg in kvps) {
        form.AddField(arg.Key, arg.Value.ToString());
    }
    form.AddField("pseudo", this._pseudo);
    form.AddField("jeton", this._dernierJeton.ToString());
    StartCoroutine(SendToServer(
        new WWW(this._URL, form.data, headers)
    )); 
}
```

Now, there's a warning saying that calling new `WWW(this._URL, form.data, headers)` is obsolete, I should use the one with the dictionnary. The declarations are like this:

```
    public WWW(string url, byte[] postData, Dictionary<string, string> headers);
    [Obsolete("This overload is deprecated. Use the one with Dictionary argument.")]
    public WWW(string url, byte[] postData, Hashtable headers);
```

So when I try to use the example in the link I've provided at the beginning of the question, I have a code like this, which doesn't work:

```
public static Dictionary<K, V> HashtableToDictionary<K, V>(Hashtable table)
{
    return table
      .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
      .ToDictionary(kvp => (K)kvp.Key, kvp => (V)kvp.Value);
}

public void AskServer(List<Kvp> kvps)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    Dictionary<string, string> headers = StateManager.HashtableToDictionary<string, object>(form.headers);
    if (this._lastCookies != string.Empty) {
        headers.Add("Cookie", this._lastCookies);
    }
    foreach (var arg in kvps) {
        form.AddField(arg.Key, arg.Value.ToString());
    }
    form.AddField("pseudo", this._pseudo);
    form.AddField("jeton", this._dernierJeton.ToString());
    StartCoroutine(SendToServer(
        new WWW(this._URL, form.data, headers)
    )); 
}
```

The error is: `Assets/Code/StateManager.cs(58,36): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>'`

What am I doing wrong? And is there a more effective way of doing this?

Comment: I wonder if we can do this with Unityscript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to assign `Dictionary<string, object>` to a variable of type `Dictionary<string, string>`. In order to fix the issue change

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = 
    StateManager.HashtableToDictionary<string, object>(form.headers);
```

to

```
Dictionary<string, object> headers = 
    StateManager.HashtableToDictionary<string, object>(form.headers);
```

or

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = 
    StateManager.HashtableToDictionary<string, string>(form.headers);
```

Comment: Ok, but now I have another error: `Assets/Code/StateManager.cs(51,12): error CS1061: Type `System.Collections.Hashtable' does not contain a definition for `Cast' and no extension method `Cast' of type `System.Collections.Hashtable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @OlivierPons Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

Comment: It works! **`\o/`** What was strange is that I didn't have the "add using" option when I was right clicking on the error, like it's displayed in such cases. Sorry for my bad english, and thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might fell over this issue (a minimal example):

```
    //make a short dictionary (only one Entry - remember to set also the
    //appropriate Length if you want to submit non Text Data

    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    headers.Add( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );

        //ADD your Form Elements wich you want to transmit
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField( "ChunkCoordinate", ChunkCoordinate );            // 0/0

        byte[] rawData = form.data;
        string url = "http://yourURL.com/addSomething.php?";

        // Post a request to an URL with our custom headers
        WWW www = new WWW(url, rawData, headers);
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the [wwwform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html) code on in unit3d's documentation needs to be updated, seeing as it still shows an example that has this exact same issue.

The problem I found with the solutions above at first is when you look at the www reference is it the www class requires a hashtable as the third argument. it seemed then that this solution would work:

```
Hashtable header = new Hashtable(form.headers);
```

The only problem with that is that using the hashtable is obsolete, so you actually have to use a dictionary. Just remember you may also need to then add

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```